# How can i set custom inputviewcontroller / inputView for WKWebView?

Tags: wkwebview, inputview, uiinputviewcontroller

Is there any way of customizing inputView when editing a WKWebView? It doesn't have the set inputView as UITextView has, but an alternative may be to just load a custom inputViewController (custom keyboard) for the whole app. I haven't found a way to force use a inputViewController for a specific time/place in the app. Is there a way to do this?